# box2d cocos2d. Calculate direction for SetLinearVelocity

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone, direction

I'm create [character who moved](https://skitch.com/roma86/ek34f/skitched-20120805-151751) by screen.

Character is sensor kinematic body in box2d world. 
Kinematic because, i want entity with collision, but without gravity. I'm try use sprites, but there are many problem with collision bounding box, because physic bodes sprite animated.

For transition logic i plan to use SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2).

body->SetLinearVelocity(0, 0.5) move body top, body->SetLinearVelocity(0.5, 0.5) move body by 45 angle, it's work correct.

But i'm stupid – how move body using this method to different point.

In other words i need create analog CCMoveTo. Problem – how calculate true b2Vec2 for SetLinearVelocity.

Also, if you know better way for transition body by screen, please share your thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O'k. On the cocos2d-iphone.org forum i get answer.Thanks, guys.

```
CGPoint direction = ccp( targetPos.x - startPos.x, targetPos.y - startPos.y );
direction = ccpNormalize(direction);
float speed = 0.25f;
b2Vec2 vel = b2Vec2( speed*direction.x/kPointsToMeterRatio, speed*direction.y/kPointsToMeterRatio );
body->SetLinearVelocity(vel);
```

Comment: Hey Roma i need some help regarding jumping sprite. Can you help me??